# References in another Schema - mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

I'm doing some tests with MongoDB and NodeJS for a new project.
Searching the documentation I found that it is possible to make references to other collections and bring this data to JSON.

It was then that I decided to perform the following test:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

    const userSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      posts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
      }]
    })
    const userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

    const postSchema = new Schema({
      title: {
        type: String
      },
      content: {
        type: String
      },
      author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    })
    const postModel = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

    const saveUser = new userModel({
      name: 'user',
      email: 'user@email.com'
    })
    saveUser.save()

    const savePost = new postModel({
      title: 'Lorem',
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      author: saveUser._id
    })
    savePost.save()


    postModel.find()
      .populate('User')
      .exec((err, post) => {
        console.log(post)
      })
```

However the return of JSON is:

```js
    {
      _id: 5edd0c24a4f42b0e126f4b15,
      title: 'Lorem',
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      author: 5edd0c24a4f42b0e126f4b14,
      __v: 0
     }
```

When should it be:

```js
    {
      _id: 5edd0c24a4f42b0e126f4b15,
      title: 'Lorem',
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      author: {
        _id: 5edd0c24a4f42b0e126f4b14,
        name: user,
        email: user@email.com
      },
      __v: 0
    }
```

Does anyone know any solution to this problem where I can insert for all my new Schemas?

Comment: If I comment out the .populate ('User') line it returns the first JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `populate` you should provide the field name provided in `postSchema`. So should replace `.populate('User')` with `.populate('author')`.

Since the `post` requires the `author` `_id` you should save the `post` only after the `author` is successfully saved

```js
const saveUser = new userModel({
  name: "user",
  email: "user@email.com",
});
saveUser.save((err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    const savePost = new postModel({
      title: "Lorem",
      content: "Lorem Ipsum",
      author: saveUser._id,
    });
    savePost.save();
  }
});
```